# MySQL: Can I constraint column values in one table to values in a column in another table, by DB design only?

Tags: sql, mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

Example:

Table "persons", Column "surname" may only contain values predefined in

Table "names", Column "surnames", which would contain a collection of surnames acceptable for the purpose.

Can I achieve this by design (i.e. without involving any validation code)? On a MyISAM table? No? On InnoDB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for is a foreign key constraint.  [You'd need to use InnoDB - quote](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html):

> For storage engines other than InnoDB, MySQL Server parses the FOREIGN KEY  syntax in CREATE TABLE  statements, but does not use or store it.

To add a foreign key constraint within the CREATE TABLE statement for `PERSONS`:

```
FOREIGN KEY (surname) REFERENCES names(surnames)
```

Using an ALTER TABLE statement if the tables already exist:

```
ALTER TABLE persons 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (surname) REFERENCES names(surname)
```

Be aware that if you use the `ALTER TABLE` statement, the data in the `PERSONS` table can only contain surname values that exist in the `NAMES.surname` table - it can not be applied until after the data has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For MyISAM tables you can achieve desired functionality by using triggers.

For instance (validate insert),

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT ON persons
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE tmp_surname varchar(100);
  SELECT surname into tmp_surname FROM names WHERE surname = NEW.surname; 
  IF (tmp_surname IS NULL) THEN
    INSERT INTO t1(id,value) VALUES('aaa'); #raise an 'exception'
  END IF;    
END;//
delimiter;
```

Mysql doesn't have exceptions, but you can terminate execution(and, consequently, 'rollback' changes) by creating an invalid statement

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I'll add an example to validate insert. You will need to do the same for update